# How can I select specific keys in array of object with an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of color like this

```
var colors = ['yellow','blue']
```

And my data base return me

```
var db = [{name : "Paul", yellow : "it's yellow or not", pink : null, red : null,blue:"it's darkblue"},{name : "Eva", yellow : "it's yellow of course", pink : null, red : null,blue:"it's light blue"}]
```

So I wanted to show in an other array only the color which are in the color array (the first array)
This is what I want

```
var newArray = [{name : "Paul", yellow : "it's yellow or not", blue:"it's darkblue"},{name : "Eva", yellow : "it's yellow of course",blue:"it's light blue"}]
```

This is what I do

```
    var colors = ['yellow','blue']
    var db = [{name : "Paul", yellow : "it's yellow or not", pink : null, red : null,blue:"it's darkblue"},{name : "Eva", yellow : "it's yellow of course", pink : null, red : null,blue:"it's light blue"}]

    var newArray = db.map(x => {
        var selectedColors = colors.map(y => { return { [y]: x[y] } })
        return {
            name : x.name ,
            ...selectedColors 
        }
    })
```

But i have something like this (example with 1 row) :

```
{
    0 : {yellow : "it's yellow or not"},
    1 : {blue: "it's darkblue"},
    name : "Paul"
}
```

but I want this

```
{
    yellow : "it's yellow or not",
    blue: "it's darkblue",
    name : "Paul"
}
```

Comment: For each object in `db`, using `colors.reduce` take a property from the object that corresponds to the current element of `colors`

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine can you please show me how to do this.
I never use reduce I don't really understand how it works

Answer (score 3):

For each object in `db`,  iterate over `colors` and take a property from the object that corresponds to the current element of `colors`:

```
const db = [/* Your array of objects here */];
const colors = [/* Your array of color names here */];

const newArray = db.map((object) => {
  const excerpt = {
    name: object.name,
  };

  for (const color of colors) {
    excerpt[color] = object[color];
  }

  return excerpt;
});
```

If you care about number of lines, you could use `.reduce` method instead:

```
const array = db.map((object) => colors.reduce((excerpt, color) => ({
  ...excerpt,
  [color]: object[color],
}), {
  name: object.name,
}));
```

Comment: wow reduce is that simple ok thank you so much I guess I'm understand a bit how it works THANK YOU

Comment: @user10863293 You're welcome, but `.reduce` isn't specific to the problem. I've changed out to simple iteration. With `.reduce` the code uses less lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Either use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as the last step:

```js
const dbWithFilteredEntries = db.map(({ name, ...entry }) => {
  const selectedColors = colors.map(color => ({
    [color]: entry[color]
  }));
  
  return Object.assign({ name }, ...selectedColors);
});
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const db = [
  {
    name: "Paul",
    yellow: "it's yellow or not",
    pink: null,
    red: null,
    blue: "it's darkblue"
  },
  {
    name: "Eva",
    yellow: "it's yellow of course",
    pink: null,
    red: null,
    blue: "it's light blue"
  }
];

const colors = ['yellow', 'blue']

const dbWithFilteredEntries = db.map(({ name, ...entry }) => {
  const selectedColors = colors.map(color => ({
    [color]: entry[color]
  }));
  
  return Object.assign({ name }, ...selectedColors);
});

console.log(dbWithFilteredEntries);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

...or use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const dbWithFilteredEntries = db.map(({ name, ...entry}) => {
  return colors.reduce((newEntry, color) => {
    newEntry[color] = entry[color];
    return newEntry;
  }, { name });
});
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```js
const dbWithFilteredEntries = db.map(({ name, ...entry }) => {
  const newEntry = { name };

  for (const color of colors) {
    newEntry[color] = entry[color];
  }

  return newEntry;
});
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const db = [
  {
    name: "Paul",
    yellow: "it's yellow or not",
    pink: null,
    red: null,
    blue: "it's darkblue"
  },
  {
    name: "Eva",
    yellow: "it's yellow of course",
    pink: null,
    red: null,
    blue: "it's light blue"
  }
];

const colors = ['yellow', 'blue']

const dbWithFilteredEntries = db.map(({ name, ...entry}) => {
  return colors.reduce((newEntry, color) => {
    newEntry[color] = entry[color];
    return newEntry;
  }, { name });
});

console.log(dbWithFilteredEntries);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in maximum performance you could generate a map function:

```js
const db = [
  {
    name: "Paul",
    yellow: "it's yellow or not",
    pink: null,
    red: null,
    blue: "it's darkblue"
  },
  {
    name: "Eva",
    yellow: "it's yellow of course",
    pink: null,
    red: null,
    blue: "it's light blue"
  }
];

const colors = ['yellow', 'blue'];

const mapFn = new Function('person', 
  'return {name: person.name, ' + 
    colors.map(color => color + ': person.' + color).join(', ')
  + '};'
);

const result = db.map(mapFn);
console.log(result);
```

And the benchmark (couldn't include KooiInc's answer, it's like 100x slower than other answers):

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const chunk = [
        {
            name: "Paul",
            yellow: "it's yellow or not",
            pink: null,
            red: null,
            blue: "it's darkblue"
        },
        {
            name: "Eva",
            yellow: "it's yellow of course",
            pink: null,
            red: null,
            blue: "it's light blue"
        }
    ];

    const db = [];
    let count = 1000000;

    while (count--) db.push(...chunk);

    const colors = ['yellow', 'blue'];

    // @benchmark InSync

    db.map(({ name, ...entry }) => {
        return colors.reduce((newEntry, color) => {
            newEntry[color] = entry[color];
            return newEntry;
        }, { name });
    });

    // @benchmark 3limin4t0r

    const fields = ["name", ...colors];
    db.map((record) => (
        Object.fromEntries(fields.map(field => [field, record[field]]))
    ));

    // @benchmark Alexander
    const mapFn = new Function('person', 'return {name: person.name, ' + colors.map(color => color + ': person.' + color).join(', ') + '};');
    db.map(mapFn);

</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's a good answer but my issue with it is when I want to exec again. I have an error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at new Function

Comment: @user10863293 seems not related to the answer. could you provide your code how you use it?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the code is that you cannot define an object if you don't know how many fields you want. You can set a variable name and value by using square brackets (see [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)).

```
const object = {
  name: x.name,
  [colorVariable]: x[colorVariable],
};
```

However this doesn't help you much if you don't know how many (if any) `colorVariable`s you have.

In this scenario you want to use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert a list of key/value-pairs to an object.

```
Object.fromEntries([["name", "Paul"], ["yellow", "yellow value"], ["blue", "blue value"]]);
//=> { name: "Paul", yellow: "yellow value", blue: "blue value" }
```

To create this list we can [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over a list of fields that you want to extract.

```
Object.fromEntries(fields.map(field => [field, record[field]]));
```

To do this for every object in `db` you'll want to `map()` over each object in `db` as well.

```js
var colors = ['yellow', 'blue'];
var db = [
  { name: "Paul", yellow: "it's yellow or not",    pink: null, red: null, blue: "it's darkblue"   },
  { name: "Eva",  yellow: "it's yellow of course", pink: null, red: null, blue: "it's light blue" },
];

const fields = ["name", ...colors];
const result = db.map((record) => (
  Object.fromEntries(fields.map(field => [field, record[field]]))
));

console.log(result);
```

Note that:

```
db.map((record) => (
  something
));
```

Is short for:

```
db.map((record) => {
  return something;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce you `db` array like this (some explanation in comments):

```js
const colors = ['yellow','blue'];

const db = [{name : "Paul", yellow : "it's yellow or not", pink : null, red : null,blue:"it's darkblue"},{name : "Eva", yellow : "it's yellow of course", pink : null, red : null,blue:"it's light blue"}];

const filteredOnColors = db.reduce( (acc, obj) => {
  // filter the entries of the object
  const filtered = Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k,]) => colors.find( color => k === color ) );
  // create a new object with the filtered values and
  // the name of the original object
  const nwObj = {...Object.fromEntries(filtered), name: obj.name};
  return [...acc, nwObj ];
}, []);

console.log(filteredOnColors);
```